# How to send and receive data from a form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> **How can I send data from a react form to a node?**

- to then do validations and send them again to react
- I am new to react if there is an explanation in code I would appreciate it but I could investigate to achieve that

---

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
const ContactInfo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="title">Contact Information</h3>
      <p className="styles_description__1_Obh">
        Please take a moment to verify your contact information.
      </p>
      <div className="styles_stepsContainer__isWtJ">
        <div className="styles_stepLabel__3f9GG">
          <span className="on"></span>
        </div>
        <div className="styles_stepLabel__3f9GG">
          <span className="off"></span>
        </div>
        <div className="styles_stepLabel__3f9GG">
          <span className="off"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form className="contact">
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="form-e m-50">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-e m-50">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-e m-100">
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="form-e m-50">
            <label>DayTime Phone </label>
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-e m-50">
            <label>Evening Phone </label>
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn-form">
          enviar
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ContactInfo;
```

---

- this is the form that i have

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a simple post request example in react

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const InputTodo = () => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { description };
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/todos", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      });

      window.location = "/";
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Todo List</h1>
      <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={description}
          onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default InputTodo;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sending Data to server**

The following example is using post call to create a post in a free api in jsonplaceholder. In this example, we use handleChange for every input element's onChange event like onChange={handleChange}. In handleChange, we are setting post (via useState) of previous all post property using spread operator like ...post and update current input element's value using **[name]: value}**. Then we call post api using axios to update the post record.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function PostCreate() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const {name, value} = target;
        setPost({...post, [name]: value});
        console.log(post);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const createData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        title: post.title,
                        body: post.body,
                        userId: 1
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => console.log(json));
                console.warn(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };
        createData();
    };
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name='title' value={post.title} onChange={handleChange}
                                   className="form-control" id="title"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="position">Body</label>
                            <input type="text" name='body' value={post.body}
                                   onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="body"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostCreate;
```

Here we update data using put call:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function PostUpdate() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});
    const id = 1;

    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const {name, value} = target;
        setPost({...post, [name]: value});
        console.log(post);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const updateData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id: id,
                        title: post.title,
                        body: post.body,
                        userId: 1
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => console.log(json));
                console.warn(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };
        updateData();
    };
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name='title' value={post.title} onChange={handleChange}
                                   className="form-control" id="title"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="position">Body</label>
                            <input type="text" name='body' value={post.body}
                                   onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="body"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostUpdate;
```

**Receiving Data from server**

In the following example, we are getting all posts from api:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostPage() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        let isSubscribed = true;
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
                setIsLoading(false);

            }).catch(err => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.log(err);
        });
        return function cleanup() {
            isSubscribed = false;
            signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                {
                    isLoading ?
                        <Loader css='margin-left: 48%; margin-top: 10%' loading={isLoading}/> :
                        posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default PostPage;
```